# Which word should I use to describe the noise made by an electronic device?

Tags: single-word-requests

The noises made by electronic devices (lamps, electronic chargers, etc.) sound to me like a high-pitched，barely audible "zzzzzz".

In my mind is the word "buzz". Beyond that I don't really know.

What word should I use to describe them?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. The word coming to mind is *whine*. As it stands the question is incomplete. Please edit to add research you did before asking an expert, and specifically what words you considered and why you were not satisfied with them. Thanks.

Comment: What does the noise sound like? Click, hum, buzz, burr, beep, whir ... there's lots of electronic noises. You'll need to be more descriptive and in being that, may find your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is usually referred to as [*humming*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hum).

Comment: Also *whine* or *whistle*. *Hum* is very common for the 50 or 60 Hz line voltage sound, but I personally have never heard *hum* used for the high pitched variety. There's *ringing* but that is characteristically used when the high pitched sound is in your ears, not in a device.

Comment: While it indeed is 'referred to as humming,' it is not usually. See also: http://www.sweetwater.com/insync/hum/

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the device.  A variety of onomatopoetic words would be serviceable--buzz or hmmmmm, for instance; but your particular device might not make that noise.  In the case of sound effects, remember that you're free to improvise on the spelling.  :-)